# OpenCV module not repeating loop in Raspberry Pi 4. Working fine on windows

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, windows-10, raspberry-pi4

Let me start by saying that I am very new to Python and Raspberry Pi.

I've "made"(more like copied from a lot of diff. sources and compiled) a module on windows to capture images from a web cam on key press and save it in a folder(code attached). It is working fine on windows and repeats the loop but throws an error on Raspberry Pi after the first loop.

Code for windows:-

```
# Import Modules #######################################################################################################

from datetime import datetime
import cv2
import time
import queue
import threading


# Module Level Variables ###############################################################################################


inpath = "D:\\Python Projects\\OCR Trial2\\Input\\Training Data\\"
outpath = "D:\\Python Projects\\OCR Trial2\\Output\\"
intpath = "D:\\Python Projects\\OCR Trial2\\Intermediate\\"
file_Prefix = 'IMG100'
file_Extension = '.png'


# Class Definitions ####################################################################################################

class VideoCapture:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self._reader)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def _reader(self):
        while True:
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            if not self.q.empty():
                try:
                    self.q.get_nowait()
                except queue.Empty:
                    pass
            self.q.put(frame)

    def read(self):
        return self.q.get()

# Functions ############################################################################################################

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            windowName = "Live Video Feed"
            cv2.namedWindow(windowName)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("c"):

                time.sleep(1)
                now = datetime.now()
                formatted_time = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S.%f')[:-3]
                cam = VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
                frame1 = cam.read()
                cv2.imshow(windowName,frame1)
                cv2.imwrite(intpath + file_Prefix + formatted_time + file_Extension, frame1)
                print(formatted_time)
            else:
                continue
        except:
            pass

# Execute Code #########################################################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output for Windows:-

```
2021-01-06 17-20-05.255
2021-01-06 17-20-07.404
2021-01-06 17-20-08.601
2021-01-06 17-20-10.766
2021-01-06 17-20-12.408

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Code for Raspberry Pi:-

```
# Import Modules #######################################################################################################

from datetime import datetime
import cv2
import time
import queue
import threading

# Module Level Variables ###############################################################################################



intpath = "/home/pi/Python Images/"
file_Prefix = 'IMG100'
file_Extension = '.png'


# Class Definitions ####################################################################################################

class VideoCapture:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self._reader)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def _reader(self):
        while True:
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            if not self.q.empty():
                try:
                    self.q.get_nowait()
                except queue.Empty:
                    pass
            self.q.put(frame)

    def read(self):
        return self.q.get()

# Functions ############################################################################################################


def main():
    while True:
        try:
            windowName = "Live Video Feed"
            cv2.namedWindow(windowName)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("c"):

                time.sleep(1)
                now = datetime.now()
                formatted_time = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S.%f')[:-3]
                cam = VideoCapture(0)
                frame1 = cam.read()
                cv2.imshow(windowName,frame1)
                cv2.imwrite(intpath + file_Prefix + formatted_time + file_Extension, frame1)
                print(formatted_time)
            else:
                continue
        except:
            pass

# Execute Code #########################################################################################################


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output for Raspberry Pi :-

```
2021-01-06 17-07-59.501
[ WARN:4] global /tmp/pip-wheel-qd18ncao/opencv-python/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index

Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

Open CV module on Raspberry Pi was installed by PIP and not manually compiled. General OpenCV functions like Video capture and imshow work fine on Raspberry Pi and it captures the first photo successfully but cannot capture the second one.
Please suggest what could be the problem, what can I try next.

Edit 1 - Added this is the whole error after printing the exception:-

```
/home/pi/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python "/home/pi/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Image Capture.py"
2021-01-07 15-07-36.555
[ WARN:4] global /tmp/pip-wheel-qd18ncao/opencv-python/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Image Capture.py", line 72, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Image Capture.py", line 59, in main
    frame1 = cam.read()
  File "/home/pi/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Image Capture.py", line 42, in read
    return self.q.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/queue.py", line 170, in get
    self.not_empty.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 296, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: it may need some external C/C++ module (driver) to work with webcam

Comment: your mistake can be `cam = VideoCapture(0)` inside loop. You should use it only once - before loop. If you try to use it second time then system can't access it before it is still used by previous `cam = VideoCapture(0)`

Comment: BTW: maybe you could get better information if you wouldn't use `except: pass` - it hides error message and you don't know that there is the problem. You should use at least `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: error message plainly states "can't open camera by index" because the backend happens to be V4L2, which wants absolute paths to `/dev/video*`

Comment: @furas Thanks for the reply.1. I've added the whole error at the bottom of the question after printing the exception. 2. I tried putting  cam = VideoCapture(0) outside the loop and it gives the same error. 3. I've made the change to the code as suggested except Exception as ex: print(ex)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the reply. I did not understand the issue that you are sharing. I've checked the user rights for video (using id -a) and it has video. Plus the code does capture one instance of the image and gives the error on the second one.

Comment: I've tried and added code to release cap at the end of the loop which somewhat solves this problem but it also adds the new problem that it takes a long time to startup the camera on every key press which makes it unuseable.

Comment: why do you have that "VideoCapture" class, but you don't use any of its facilities? remove it, use the opencv VideoCapture class itself directly. I think this question is unsalvageable. you have a heap of code you don't understand and Stack Overflow's purpose is not to explain your code to you or beat it into shape. you have ignored advice in the comments (to move VideoCapture instantiation out of the loop) so we have to anticipate further ignoring of advice.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the help. I took cam = Videocapture(0) outside the loop and it is working fine now. (previously i just took cv2.namedWindow(windowName) out of the loop and thought it didn't work like an idiot). My issue is resolved. How do I mark it solved?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I had to make the video capture class to use threading as I have to process the image after capturing it and that takes time. I understand that Stack Overflow's purpose is not to explain my code to me or beat it into shape but thanks for taking the time to help anyway. Also, I did not ignore the advice. I just misunderstood it and have corrected it since in the next comment. Again thanks for all the help.

Comment: I put comment as anawer and then you can mark it as accepted. And few minutes later you can upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake can be `cam = VideoCapture(0)` inside loop.

You should create it only once - before loop.

If you try to use it second time (for example in loop) then system can't access it before it still use previous `cam = VideoCapture(0)`.